# Is the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: f(x) = 1$ bijective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse

Is the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: f(x) = 1$ bijective?

I do not think so.
The function is neither injective nor surjective.

We can make the function bijective by doing this:
$k: \{1\} \to \{1\}: k(x)= 1$

The inverse is then:
$g: \{1\} \to \{1\}: g(y) = 1$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The constant function is only bijective if it is a function between two singletons.

Comment: So g:{2}→{1}:g(y)=1 is also a correct bijective function that I derived from f, right?

Comment: @Ricardi Yes, in fact, $f$, narrowed to any singleton set is a bijection from that singleton to $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, $f$ is clearly not bijective. This can be seen if you consider that $f(0) = f(1) = 1$ so $f^{-1}(1)$ would have to map to both $0$ and $1,$ so it's not a function. (which is why injectivity is necessary)

And yes, if you limit the domain and range then you can make it bijective. The same thing can also be seen if you redefine $f(x) = x^2$ as a function from $\mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R^+,$ where $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a proper inverse because $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| = x$ when $x \in \mathbb R^+$.